# MPLab simulator PIC16 assembler infinite loop - program doesn't END

Tags: assembly, simulator, mplab

This is a little program in assembler executed in MPLAB with SIMULATOR for PIC16.

I don't understand why after the last NOP of the last three NOP the program return to the first of that group of NOP. In my mind after the three NOP the program is terminated and in fact there is END statement.

```
;MAIN
 MAIN:
    CALL INITALL

    ciclo:
    CALL COPYcurrentSFRincurrentGPR

    CALL IncrementFSRPOINTER
    CALL IncrementGPRPOINTER

    ;DECFSZ COUNTER,1    ;se counter==0 allora salta l'istruzione successiva
    ;    GOTO ciclo     ;dato che il decremento lo fa prima della verifica della condizione di 0 
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP

    ;GOTO endprogram        ;allora mettendo il counter a 0xB (12) farà 11 cicli, che volendo saltare il registro
                ;INDF (0x00) mi va bene
;endprogram:
;fine del programma
END
```

Comment: Surely there is something in memory after your code, and whatever that is must make it loop. Disassemble content of memory to see what it is and/or single step in your simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to explain you the background about Jester's comment:

**Background**

You should keep in mind what Assembler language is and how a CPU and a memory works.

In the case of PIC16 devices, program memory is organized in 12- or 14-bit units. This means that the memory can store numbers with values in the range 0-4095 or 0-16383.

When a program is executed, the CPU will read the numbers from the memory and perform some action depending on the number read from the memory.

On the 12-bit variant, the number 451 for example causes the CPU to perform an addition.

Assembler is some special programming language, where each instruction (normally) corresponds to exactly one number in memory. The instruction `ADDWF 3, 0` for example corresponds to the number 451 in memory.

**The problems**

- A CPU (normally) does not know some "END" instruction. Instead, a CPU will run endlessly.
- Your program is 7 instructions long; this is 7 numbers in the program memory.

  However, the size of the program memory of a PIC microcontroller is much more than 7 words.

  Therefore there is some memory after the 3rd `NOP` instruction. This memory will contain numbers but you don't know which numbers it contains.

  The CPU will load the numbers that are stored there and execute them. If the number 451 is stored there, it cannot know if these numbers are there intentionally (because your program contains the instruction `ADDWF 3, 0`) or if the number is stored unintentionally because your program is shorter than the memory.